# Changing type under lambda in Coq

Tags: coq

I encountered a situation where setoid rewriting does not work because convertible types are not matched by the tactic. The workaround I came up with does not work under lambda. Looking for suggestions:

```
Require Import Setoid Morphisms Relations.

(* Sample definitions *)
Record S {i o: nat} : Type.
Definition C {i o: nat} (f: @S i o):  @S i o. Admitted.
Definition B {o:nat} (z:nat): @S (o+o) o. Admitted.

(* Relations *)
Parameter R: forall {i o}, relation (@S i o).
Instance R_proper {i o}: Proper (R ==> R ==> iff) (@R i o). Admitted.
Definition Rext {i o} := pointwise_relation nat (@R i o).

(* Sample rewriting lemma *)
Lemma Rewrite (x:nat): forall z, R (C (@B x z)) (B z). Admitted.

Ltac Type_Fix :=
  match goal with
  | [ |- context G [ (@C (Datatypes.S _) ?o (@B ?o ?z))] ] =>
    let G' := context G[(@C (o+o) o (@B o z))] in change G'
  end.

(* Simple case. Works with workaround *)
Theorem Foo (p:nat): R (@C 2 1 (@B 1 p)) (@C 2 1 (@B 1 p)).
Proof.
  Fail setoid_rewrite Rewrite.
  repeat Type_Fix.
  repeat setoid_rewrite Rewrite.
Admitted.

(* Now try under lambda. Does not work! *)
Theorem Bar (p:nat): Rext (fun z => @C 2 1 (@B 1 z)) (fun z => @C 2 1 (@B 1 z)).
Proof.
  Fail setoid_rewrite Rewrite.
  Fail Type_Fix.
Admitted.
```

In both `Foo` and `Bar` direct application of `setoid_rewrite` fails. The problem is that type of `C (B p)` is `@S 2 1` while our rewriting lemma expects `@C (1+1) 1`. In `Foo` I was able to fix this via LTAC. However, this fix does not work under lambda in `Bar`.

Comment: `repeat setoid_rewrite Rewrite.` in the proof of `Foo` does not do anything.

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified my example and removed `R_proper` instance. Just edited the question to add it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three solutions:

---

1. Flip the order of your arguments, to help `setoid_rewrite` pick up the right terms even though it's using left-to-right inference.

Your example becomes:

```
Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid Coq.Classes.Morphisms Coq.Relations.Relations.

(* Sample definitions *)
Record S {o i: nat} : Type.
Definition C {o i: nat} (f: @S o i):  @S o i. Admitted.
Definition B {o:nat} (z:nat): @S o (o+o). Admitted.

(* Relations *)
Parameter R: forall {o i}, relation (@S o i).
Definition Rext {o i} := pointwise_relation nat (@R o i).

(* Sample rewriting lemma *)
Lemma Rewrite (x:nat): forall z, R (C (@B x z)) (B z). Admitted.

Global Instance R_Proper {o i} : Proper (R ==> R ==> Basics.flip Basics.impl) (@R o i).
Proof.
Admitted.

(* Simple case. Works with workaround *)
Theorem Foo (p:nat): R (@C 1 2 (@B 1 p)) (@C 1 2 (@B 1 p)).
Proof.
  setoid_rewrite Rewrite.
Admitted.

Global Instance Rext_Proper {o i}
  : Proper
      ((pointwise_relation nat R)
         ==> (pointwise_relation nat R)
         ==> Basics.flip Basics.impl) (@Rext o i).
Proof.
Admitted.

(* Now try under lambda. Does not work! *)
Theorem Bar (p:nat): Rext (fun z => @C 1 2 (@B 1 z)) (fun z => @C 1 2 (@B 1 z)).
Proof.
  setoid_rewrite Rewrite.
Admitted.
```

---

2. Make `Type_Fix` smarter.

You could do this instead:

```
Ltac Type_Fix :=
  progress
    repeat match goal with
           | [ |- context G [@C _ ?o] ]
             => progress let G' := context G[@C (o+o) o] in change G'
           end.
```

This version only requires that the `o` argument to `C` not be a binder, and allows the `f` argument to be a binder.  I've replaced `Datatypes.S _` with `_` and used `progress` to ensure that we find places where it makes sense to change; this makes the tactic more general and allows it to fix other representations as well (for example, `@C 0 0`).

---

3. Use `match` to fill in the relevant argument to `Rewrite`.

You could replace `setoid_rewrite Rewrite` with something like

```
  match goal with
  | [ |- context[C (@B ?x _)] ]
    => setoid_rewrite (Rewrite x)
  end.
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I could not change order of arguments, so your 2nd solution looks promising. The only proble is I need to restrict Type_Fix to affect only '(C (B ))' instances, so, for example, '(C (X))' won't be affected. I tried to tweak your LTAC for that but could not make it work.

Comment: Why do you need `C X` to not be affected?  Can't you just change it back afterwards?

Comment: B is special because there is a relation between 1st and second arguments of its type and it always have type S (n+n) n. This is not true in general and some other definitions of type S which could be in place of B as a parameter of C may not have such dependency, and thus changing their type according to `S (n+n) n` pattern would be incorrect.

Comment: By the way, your suggestion of specifying a parameter to rewrite worked for me as a valid workaround. I do not think I fully understand how it works. My naive understanding that in general there is a problem with setoid_rewrite unifying (1+1) and 2 in type parameters. For some reason, it works if it is a 2nd argument (your 1st suggestion) but not first or if it is specified implicitly as rule argument (3rd solution).

Comment: This tactic will not generate ill-typed goals.  If it happens to be the case that the first argument to `C` does not unify with the second argument plus itself, the `context` replacement will fail, and it will move on to the next match.  (In 8.4, `context` could generate ill-typed terms, but I think `change` would fail in 8.4, and the behavior would be the same.)  Do you have a concrete goal that it behaves poorly on?

Comment: The issue with plain `setoid_rewrite` is not in unifying (1+1) and 2, but in unifying `?x+?x` with 2 for some evar `?x`.  Alas, Coq is not smart enough to delay that unification problem until after it sees that `?x` must be 1 by the second argument, and so it fails before it even gets there.  I think there's a bug report somewhere on GitHub about this, which I opened a while back.

Comment: Yes. If we add the following definition `Definition X {i o:nat} (z:nat): @S i o. Admitted.` and change Foo to `Theorem Foo (p:nat): R (@C 2 1 (@B 1 p)) (@C 2 1 (@X 2 1 p)).` The Type_Fix will change the second C from `C 2 1` to `C (1+1) 1`. While the type is technically correct since there is no fundamental relation between 1st and 2nd argument this just complicates the goal and may case rewriting problem similar to one we had started with. I would prefer to keep (C 2 1) intact at right-hand side but change only at LHS. (https://gist.github.com/vzaliva/0974afadb315b9ba771c233214387ad0 )

Comment: The easy way to do this is to write `Type_Unfix` that reverses the change afterwards.  The hard way to do this is to define `C' := C` and `C'' := C`, execute `change (@C) with (@C')`, and then do `repeat (change (@C') with (@C'') at 1; lazymatch goal with |- context G[@C'' ?i ?o (@B _ _)] => change (@C'' i o) with (@C (o + o) o) | _ => change (@C'') with (@C) end)` (or similar; I haven't tested this).  The idea here is that you use two aliases of `C`, one to mark instances you haven't processed yet, and one to mark the current instance, and then you process them one by one.